# Intersections in Kruskal's Minimum spanning tree

Tags: algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

I find that some edges of Minimum Spanning Tree (MST) overlap using the union find method detailed [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/772779/Kruskal-Algorithm-in-Csharp), with modifications - using `float` instead of `integer` weights, using `integer` values instead of `string` IDs. The grey lines in image below are the MST edges and green / blue edges are shape boundaries.

The edge cost is the euclidean distance between the nodes.

Example showing vertex IDs. Edge weight is added below:[image]

Instead of node 87 -> 138 (weight = 17.7) and 55 -> 134 (weight = 9.49), should it not be 55 -> 138 and 87 -> 134? Is the implementation wrong or can this happen with the algorithm itself?

Please ignore the numbers in brackets besides the vertex numbers (they are the combined weight of edges which connect to each node).

Same example, zoomed out to show other edge weights (removed vertex numbers to remove clutter):
[image]

P.S. I found that the distance between 55 -> 138 and 87 -> 134 are exactly the same (12.20656).

Comment: " some modifications such as" - any modifications *apart from* having `float` rather than `int` weights? You need to tell us about them. Also, include your input data in a form other than a blurry screenshot...

Comment: @AakashM, the screenshot appears fine on my screen - do you find it difficult to discern the numbers?

Comment: What are the numbers in brackets? what are the edge weights (that is, the actual inputs to the algorithm...)

Comment: Added what the numbers in brackets mean. Will add edge weights...

Comment: And the other edges?

Comment: Added nearby edge weights...

Comment: So are there actually edges joining 55 <-> 138 and 87 <-> 134 ??

Comment: Nope - the images show whatever edges are calculated by the algorithm without any filters...

Comment: The algorithm doesn't *calculate* edges, it *selects* edges from the graph. Does your graph actually contain edges joining 55 <-> 138 and 87 <-> 134 ? If so what are their weights?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158317/discussion-between-vignesh-and-aakashm).

Comment: Unfortunately, adding minor weight differences to edges does not resolve the problem, as stated in my solution a bit earlier.

Comment: Does the fact that edge 55 -> 138 crosses your shape boundary cause this?

Comment: Nope, the edges do not cross and the shape boundary is not part of the algorithm. It is only used to filter out any intersecting edges which are then fed to Kruskal's algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, based on the questions asked by AakashM.

Specifically, this happened because the edge cost between 55 -> 138 and 87 -> 134 are exactly the same. This happened in my case since I'm generating a shape using an image, hence the distance between points is quantized.

Inspired by this, I added very small random weights (less than the least distance distance between pixels) to the edges which (edit: **has not**) solved the issue!

So, the algorithm remains good for euclidean MST, and my specific implementation contains a caveat.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your second image (specifically the unconnected island near the top), it looks like you are pruning your edge list to those that do not cross the shape boundary.

As such, edges 55 <-> 138 and 78 <-> 138 are not available to the Kruskal algorithm and the only edge connecting vertex 138 to the rest of the graph connects to vertex 87.

Comment: You are right, let me look at the problem from this direction!